# How do I read a disk frame that's already been saved?

Tags: r, disk.frame

I saved a disk frame to its output directory and then restarted my R session.

I'd like to read the existing disk frame instead of recreating it elsewhere.

How might I be able to accomplish this? My folder is called `outdir.df`

This is how I saved the disk frame

```
  mydf <- csv_to_disk.frame("myfile.csv",
                    in_chunk_size = 1e8,
                    shardby = "col",
                    outdir = "diskframe/outdir.df"
  )
```

Comment: How did you save this disk frame? With `save.image`? `saveRDS`? Something else? Where on disk was your disk frame data stored? If its in an R temporary directory then its gone once you quit R.

Comment: I added details. Disk frame stores the chunks locally into a file on my machine. In this case , the output directory is called outdir.df

Comment: What about `mydf <- disk.frame("diskframe/outdir.df")`? (Or `"thisisadiskframe.df"` or whatever your path is, you mention two here.)

Comment: It should be located in mydf?

Comment: @r2evans, that worked perfectly. It looks like the variable isn't actually loading any data, it's just making a reference to a location for the disk frame chunks. No load time.

Comment: Can you add that as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `disk.frame`'s preferred method is to open a reference to the disk location, using

```r
library(disk.frame)
mydf <- disk.frame("diskframe/outdir.df")
```

Since it's just a reference and not actually loading all of the data (since the stated intention of `disk.frame` is to not load all data into memory), this should be nearly instantaneous.